# Direct Product Decomposition

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $\{R_α\}$ be a nonempty collection of commutative rings.
Then each $x\in R=∏R_α $ can be written as $x=r+e$ where $r\in reg(R)$ (the set of regular elements of
R) and $e\in Id(R)$ (the set of idempotent elements of R) **if and only if** for each $R_α$, every $x_α\in R_α$ can be written as $x_α=r_α+e_α$ where $r_α\in reg(R_α)$ and $e_α\in Id(R_α)$.

This is Proposition 2.10 in ["Weakly Clean Rings and Almost Clean Rings" by Ahn & Anderson (2006).](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/38371099_Weakly_Clean_Rings_and_Almost_Clean_Rings)

How to prove that?
By homomorphism we can get the idempotent in $R=∏R_α $ and $R_α$. I don't have any idea how to work with the regular elements.

Here is how homomorphism works for idempotent element:
There is a homomorphism mapping $π_α:R→R_α$ that is $π_α(x)=x_α$, with $x=(x_a)∈∏R_α=R$.
We know that homomorphism preserve operation :
For all $x,y∈R$,
$π_α(x+y)=π_α (x)+π_α (y)$ and $π_α(xy)=π_α (x) π_α (y)$.
Then we know that the image of an idempotent element in $R=∏R_α$ id is an idempotent in $R_α$.
For all $e=(e_α)∈Id(R)$ we can get $(π_α (e))^2=π_α (e^2 )=π_α (e)$

Comment: your statement does not make sense. On the right hand side  of your "if and only  if" statement there is a free variable alpha. Doyu you mean "...if and only if for all alpha ..." or "... if and only if there is an alpha ..."

Comment: There is really no insight needed to solve this question at all. All you have to do is verify what it says...

Comment: @miracle173 Yes, its "...if and only if for all alpha..".

Comment: I don't understand "By homomorphism we can get the idempotent in R and Rα" can you elaborate this?

Comment: Why do you think that this statement ist true?

Comment: This is Proposition 2.10 in "Weakly Clean Rings and Almost Clean Rings" by Ahn & Anderson (2006). https://www.researchgate.net/publication/38371099_Weakly_Clean_Rings_and_Almost_Clean_Rings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These homomorphisms $\pi_\alpha$ are called *projections*.
With your homomorphism-argument you proved that if $e$ is an idempotent element of $R$ then $\pi_\alpha(e)$ is a idempotent element in $R_\alpha$. But you did not prove the opposite direction: if $e_\alpha$ is and idempotent element of $R_\alpha$, for all $\alpha$, then $(e_\alpha)_\alpha$ is and idempotent element of $R$.

Instead of investigating the homomorphisms further let's use the definition of the direct product.

Remember that notations like $\{R_\alpha\}$ and $\Pi R_\alpha$ are shortcuts and hide that there must be a set where the $\alpha$ is from, the index set. So lets call this set $A$.
 So $\{R_\alpha\}$ actually is $\{R_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in A}$ or $\{R_\alpha\mid \alpha \in A\}$ and $\Pi R_\alpha$ is $\Pi_{\alpha \in A} R_\alpha$.
An element $r \in \Pi_{\alpha \in A} R_\alpha$ is a function $r:A\mapsto R$ and for this function we use the notation $(r_\alpha)_{\alpha\in R}$ or $(r_\alpha)_\alpha$ for short, too. The sum $r^{(1)}+r^{(2)}$ is the functions that maps $\alpha$ to $r^{(1)}(\alpha)+r^{(1)}(\alpha)$, $^{(1)}\cdot ^{(2)}$ is defined ins a similar way.

If $e\in R$ we write $(e_\alpha)_\alpha$ for it. If it is an idempotent element we have
$$(e_\alpha)_\alpha=(e_\alpha)_\alpha\cdot(e_\alpha)_\alpha \tag 1$$
Fom the definition of $\cdot$ in $R$ follows
$$(e_\alpha)_\alpha\cdot(e_\alpha)_\alpha = (e_\alpha\cdot e_\alpha)_\alpha\tag 2$$
an so
$$(e_\alpha)_\alpha=(e_\alpha \cdot e_\alpha)_\alpha\tag 3$$
which is equivalent to
$$\forall \alpha\in A\!:\; e_\alpha=e_\alpha\cdot e_\alpha\tag 4$$
This is what you have already proved.

Now we prove  the opposite direction. 
It is easy to see that from $(4)$ follows $(3)$ and that $(2)$ holds. From $(2)$ and $(3)$ follows $(1)$.

So we have proved that $(e_\alpha)$ is idempotent if and only if for all $\alpha$ is $ e_\alpha$  idempotent.

The $0$-element of $R$ is $(0)_\alpha$. If $(r_\alpha)_\alpha\in R$ is a regular element then for each $\alpha$ the element $r_\alpha$ is a regular element in $R_\alpha$. Otherwise if $r_{\alpha_0}$ is a zero divisor, than $r_{\alpha_0}\cdot b=0$ for a $b \in R_{\alpha_0}$ and $b\ne0$. If we set 
$$c_\alpha=b, \alpha=\alpha_0$$
$$c_\alpha=0, \alpha\ne\alpha_0$$
then $(c_\alpha)_\alpha\ne 0$ and $(r_\alpha)_\alpha\cdot (c_\alpha)_\alpha=(0)_\alpha$, so $r$ would not be regular. If $r_\alpha\in R_\alpha$ is regular for each $\alpha$ then $(r_\alpha)_\alpha$ is regular, too.

Now similar statement  for a decomposition of a ring element $x$ into $e+r$, where $e$ is idempotent and $r$ is regular follows immediately.

Note:
For zero divisor the following holds:
If $n_\alpha)_\alpha$ is a zero divisor of $R$ if and only if there exists at least one $\alpha$ such that $n_\alpha$ is a zero divisor in $R_\alpha$.

In symbolic notation

$$(r_\alpha)_\alpha \in \text{Idempotent}(\Pi_\alpha R_\alpha)\Longleftrightarrow \forall \alpha\!:r_\alpha \in \text{Idempotent}(R_\alpha)$$
$$(r_\alpha)_\alpha \in \text{Regular}(\Pi_\alpha R_\alpha)\Longleftrightarrow \forall \alpha\!:r_\alpha \in \text{Regular}(R_\alpha)$$
$$(r_\alpha)_\alpha \in \text{Zerodivisor}(\Pi_\alpha R_\alpha)\Longleftrightarrow \exists \alpha\!:r_\alpha \in \text{Zerodivisor}(R_\alpha)$$
The following holds per definition of "regular"
$$(r_\alpha)_\alpha \in \text{Regular}(\Pi_\alpha R_\alpha)\Longleftrightarrow \lnot((r_\alpha)_\alpha \in \text{Zerodivisor}(\Pi_\alpha R_\alpha))\tag{11}$$
This is the property of Zerodivisors we have to prove:
$$\lnot((r_\alpha)_\alpha \in \text{Zerodivisor}(\Pi_\alpha R_\alpha))\Longleftrightarrow \lnot(\exists \alpha\!:r_\alpha \in \text{Zerodivisor}(R_\alpha))\tag{12}$$
and the right hand site term is logically equivalent to
$$ \lnot(\exists \alpha\!:r_\alpha \in \text{Zerodivisor}(R_\alpha))\Longleftrightarrow \forall \alpha\!:\lnot (r_\alpha \in \text{Zerodivisor}(R_\alpha))\tag{13}$$
and again by the definition of "regular" we get
$$\forall \alpha\!:\lnot (r_\alpha \in \text{Zerodivisor}(R_\alpha))\Longleftrightarrow\forall \alpha\!:r_\alpha \in \text{Regular}(R_\alpha)\tag{14}$$
To prove $(12)$ you prove 
$$(r_\alpha)_\alpha \in \text{Zerodivisor}(\Pi_\alpha R_\alpha)\Longleftrightarrow \exists \alpha\!:r_\alpha \in \text{Zerodivisor}(R_\alpha)\tag{15}$$
I hope it is clear how to do this

Comment: The motivation of the proof is to take the negation of biconditional (bi-implication) of zero divisor. But if we take the counter example, we can consider the ring $\Pi (Z_6)_\alpha$ and choose $(3,1,1)\in Z(\Pi (Z_6)_\alpha)$ because there is a nonzero element $(2,0,0)\in \Pi (Z_6)_\alpha$. But there is $\alpha$ that $1_\alpha\in (Z_6)_\alpha)$ is not an a zero divisor in $(Z_6)_\alpha$

Comment: yes, you are  right. I have to think about this.

Comment: @chandara I repaired the proof now. it is rather simple. In my wrong try I used the definition of zero divisor and had problems with the negation of the statement.

Comment: We would like to proof that "if $(r_α)_α∈R$ is a regular element then for each $α$ the element $r_α$ is a regular element in  $R_α$" so we use the contrapositive, that is  "if  for each $α$ the element $r_α$ is a zero divisor in  $R_α$ then $(r_α)_α∈R$ is a zero divisor", isn't it?

Comment: @chandara In the previous version I used the zero divisor property, now I proved it directly. But I added a note at the end of my post how these is related to the zero divisor.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $x=(x_\alpha)_\alpha$ is an idempotent /regular if and only if for all $\alpha$, $x_\alpha$ is an idempotent/regular. (Just apply the definition of the product law in $R$, and the definitions of idempotent/regular).

Comment: I'm still not sure how it works in the case of regular element.

Comment: @chandara add to your post how this works for idempotent elements